# Android SDK setup help

Tags: android

Im having some weird issues setting up the SDK in eclipse, when i go to make a project i cant select anything in the build target. I have installed the eclipse plugin and the SDK but im not sure whats going on. Some help please, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to see the build target because you have not installed any Android virtual device in your AVD Manager.
AVD Manager is located  at the same place where SDK Manager resides(in windows startmenu-programs-android SDK Tools)
Open AVD Manager with administrator privilege and install any build target you choose. Then try in the eclipse . It will work fine.